# Two Emojione area in one page

Tags: jquery, css, emoji, emojione

I have big problem, because I would like set two different emojioneare in one page (in textarea) but I can't change height of this emojionearea.

HTML

```
<textarea id="Emoji" ></textarea>
<textarea id="Emoji1"></textarea>
```

JQ

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Emoji").emojioneArea({});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Emoji1").emojioneArea();
  $('.emojionearea').css({height:'500px'})
});
```

And the problem is that css() in jq not working

Thanks for your help and time`

Comment: could you please create a https://jsfiddle.net/ of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `textarea` inside container and then set style on `.emojionearea-editor` element.

HTML

```
<div id="container1">
  <textarea id="Emoji1"> 3em height</textarea>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="container2">
  <textarea id="Emoji2"> 9em height</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container1 .emojionearea-editor {
  min-height: 3em !important;
}

#container2 .emojionearea-editor {
  min-height: 9em !important;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Emoji1").emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom",
    tonesStyle: "bullet",
  });
  $("#Emoji2").emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom",
    tonesStyle: "bullet",
  });
});
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/dorjv2ej/

Answer (score 0):

How to use add dynamic id to use in php in every post .

Please check below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var gid= $('.dp_comment').data("comment-id");

    $("#comment_"+gid+"").emojioneArea({});
  });
```